# My css sprites are not showing up at all, I have tried everything

Tags: html, css, sprite

I am new here and just learning to code a website, so far I had hit a snag. When I try to use my `background: url(../images/sprite.png)` it does not seem to work, I got it to work on my navigation bar, but when I try to do it on my billboard section area it does not want to work with me at all. Here is my HTML

```
<div id="container_header">

<div id="container_header2">

<div id="ram_logo">
    <a href="#">
        <img src="images/ram_logo.png" border="0" alt="logo" />
    </a>
</div>

<div id="menu">
    <ul>
        <li id="features"><a href="#"><span>Features & Specs</span></a></li>
        <li id="photos"><a href="#"><span>Photo Gallery</span></a></li>
        <li id="brochure"><a href="#"><span>Brochure</span></a></li>
        <li id="getaquote"><a href="#"><span>Get A Quote</span></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="clear">

</div>
</div>
</div>

<div id="container_billboard">

<div id="truck_home">

</div>

<div id="billboard_title">
    <p id="title_allnew">THE ALL NEW</p>
    <p id="title_ram">2013 Ram 1500</p>
    <p id="title_laramie">Laramie Longhorn </p>    
    <p id="title_starting">Starting at</p>
    <p id="title_price">$20,500</p>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <div id="title_getaquote">
        <a href="#">
        </a>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="clear">
</div>
</div>
```

now the elements I am wanting to target are: `<div id="truck_home">` and `<div id="title_getaquote">
        <a href="#">
        </a>
    </div>`

here is my css:

```
#truck_home {
    background-image: url(/images/sprite.png) no-repeat 0px -69px;
    margin-top: -20px;
    margin-right: -150px;
    float: right;
    height: 293px;
    width: 655px;

    }
#title_getaquote {
    background-image: url(/images/sprite.png) no-repeat -163px -365px;
    text-align: left;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-left: 165px;
    }
```

so I am not sure what I am doing wrong here, I tried doing `background-position: 0 0`

please if anyone can help it would be really appreciated. I have been trying to figure this out for a few hours now...

Answer (score 2):

In your CSS, use `background: ...` instead of `background-image: ...`.

Answer (score 0):

**Demo**

http://jsfiddle.net/raunakkathuria/MA8pN/

If you are using background-image don't include `no-repeat -163px -365px` in it, because `background-image` is for specifying url only, in this case you have to individually specify

```
background-repeat: no-repeat
background-position:-163px -365px;
```

or just update `background-image` as said by DXL also